# Querydsl java order by custom input list

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, querydsl

How to sort resultset by a custom input list which is provided in `where clause IN values`.

Below is my query in SQL for oracle:

```
SELECT col1, col2, avg(col3)
FROM   table1
WHERE  table1.col1 IN (12340417, 12340418, 12340419, 12340420)
GROUP  BY col2, col1
ORDER  BY col2, instr('12340417, 12340418, 12340419, 12340420', col1) ;
```

So, basically I am looking for a replacement of `instr` expression above in querydsl (Expression to pass to OrderSpecifier) e.g. :

```
new OrderSpecifier(this.sortOrder, expression)
```

Is there any other way to sort result set by custom list `(12340417, 12340418, 12340419, 12340420)` in `querydsl`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it in standard SQL, you can use a CASE expression:

```
QUser user = new QUser("");
List<String> guids = new ArrayList<>();
guids.add("a");
guids.add("b");
guids.add("c");
guids.add("d");

CaseForEqBuilder<String>.Cases<Integer, NumberExpression<Integer>> cases = QUser.user.guid.when("").then(-1);
for (int i = 0; i < guids.size(); i++) {
    cases.when(guids.get(i)).then(i);
}
NumberExpression<Integer> guidExpression = cases.otherwise(-1);

QUser.user.guid.in(guids);
guidExpression.asc();
```